# Kentico 13 - Any Docker image available for kentico CMS Admin

Tags: kentico, kentico-mvc, kentico-13

I am using Kentico 13 and planning to use two docker containers, one to host the admin site and the to host the user-facing site. I have used a linux container to host the user-facing site, do you guys provide any image for Kentico 13 Admin like you have for [Kentico 12](https://hub.docker.com/r/kentico/ems).

One more question I have is related to connection string, The user-facing site (.net core application) uses a connectionstring which is present in app.config and the Kentico dll uses that connection string. Is it possible for me to move it to an environment variable instead of putting it in app settings. It would be easier for me to use a single docker image and change the environment variable to point to different DB instances.

1. Docker Image: Is it possible to have two docker images (one windows based for admin and the other linux based)? And is there any docker image available for kentico 13 just like Kentico 12.
2. Connection String: Since the connection string is present in the appsettings file, I need to make multiple docker images (one per environment). If I can use the connection string from environment variables then it would be easier for me to use the single image and use differebt environment variable values for different environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge Kentico does not have an updated / public docker image for Kentico Xperience 13. Also since the admin tool is running on .NET Full Framework (4.x) it has some known issues with running inside of a container that isn't Windows based in early versions of 12 and 13. So I would check out this guide and make sure you have updated to a recent hotfix as well.

https://dev.to/truelime/top-3-reasons-to-use-docker-with-kentico-xperience-2689